# Paladins crash on character selection page

Tags: paladins

When I join a casual game of Paladins and click a character on the character selection page, the game suddenly crashes to my desktop. After that a message comes up saying 'Paladins quit unexpectedly. Do you want to reopen the app?'.

I am using a MacBook Air. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue related to the most recent update.

http://forums.paladins.com/showthread.php?48148-MAC-Game-Crashes-on-Champion-Select

Hi-rez is working on a Hot-fix.

Problem has been fixed.